# dynamically set the header menu data in webix?

Tags: webix

dynamically set the header menudata like columns below

headermenu: { id: "headerMenu", css: "webix-contextmenu", width: 150, data: getHeaderMenuData(),

}

Like setting externally for columns, function add_column(){ var columns = webix.toArray(grid.config.columns); columns.insertAt({ id:"c"+webix.uid(), header:"New column" },2); grid.refreshColumns(); }

is there a way that I can set for headerMenu data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally the header menu will regenerated self after refreshColumns call, and will include the newly added column. ( you may need to update to the latest version of Webix )

Also, you can add items to header menu directly, by using code like next

```
var menu_id = grid.config.headermenu;
$$(menu_id).add({
  id:"new", value:"NEW"
});
```